# Append query in ruby on rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

This method returned some record from database.

```
   def wall_record(ref_id,followers_record,pid,sd_pid)
        @Wp_rec=Wallpost.select('Wp.id as Pid,Wp.*,Wi.id as Iid,Wi.imagename,Wv.videourl,U.firstname,U.username')
        @Wp_rec=@Wp_rec.where('Wp.id > ? ', pid) if pid.present? # pid->PostId
        @Wp_rec=@Wp_rec.where('Wp.id < ? ', sd_pid) if sd_pid.present? # sd_pid -> Scroll down
        @Wp_rec=@Wp_rec.where('Wp.posted_by IN (?) ', followers_record)  if followers_record.present?
        @Wp_rec=@Wp_rec.joins('Wp INNER JOIN `epoker_wallimages` as Wi on Wi.wallpost_id = Wp.id')
        @Wp_rec=@Wp_rec.joins('INNER JOIN `epoker_users` as U on U.id = Wp.user_id')
        @Wp_rec=@Wp_rec.joins('INNER JOIN `epoker_wallvideos` as Wv on Wv.wallpost_id = Wp.id')
        @Wp_rec=@Wp_rec.order('Wp.id DESC') if followers_record.present?
        @Wp_rec=@Wp_rec.limit(5) #if followers_record.present?
      end
```

Now i want to add  mysql query
-> `where((Wp.posted_by != 100000 AND post_status = 1) OR (Wp.posted_by = 10000 AND post_status in (1,2)))`

How can I do this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is very easy =)

just include condition what you want into quotes:

```
where("(Wp.posted_by != 100000 AND post_status = 1) OR (Wp.posted_by = 10000 AND post_status in (1,2))")
```

you can even pass inside quotes any param you want

```
   where("(Wp.posted_by != 100000 AND post_status = #{post_status}) OR (Wp.posted_by =  #{posted_by} AND post_status in (#{post_statuses_array.join(',')}))")
```

and finally, you can make it with more rails-like approach

```
where("(Wp.posted_by ? != AND post_status = ?) OR (Wp.posted_by = ? AND post_status in (?))",100000, 1, 10000, [1,2])
```

**instead of Wp model you have to pass real table name!** (but as far as i can see it is your table name.. not very convenient, by the way)

Comment: The second method could leave you vulnerable to SQL injection, the third method is much preferred unless you can be absolutely sure that users have no way of putting arbitrary data into your query.